# What is an orchestra "reading session"?

Tags: terminology, orchestra

On orchestra calendars I sometimes see events called "reading sessions", such as this one: [Pittsburgh Symphony 11th Annual Reading Session](http://www.pittsburghsymphony.org/event/7740/11th-annual-reading-session)

What is a "reading session" and how does it differ from a normal concert?

Comment: READ the link - it tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes No, it doesn't. It assumes you already know what a reading session is. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: Reading is simply reading through a piece - as one would read a story. No rehearsal, just read it. Good players are quite capable of doing this. The results will be quite palatable, although after, the conductor and composer may feel the need to change things - subtly or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, it's an opportunity for new composers to hear their music played by a real orchestra, as opposed to the playback option in their notation computer software. "Reading" implies that this is usually close to sight-reading by the orchestra (and sometimes by the conductor as well!)

Comment: It also can be an opportunity for music teachers, directors, and others that are responsible for music repertoires to read through new music with a group so they can get first hand experience with music that they may want to consider for their ensembles.